# How can store Data text view data?

Tags: android

In this file i have two Edit text and one textview.I want to sum two number.then result are show in text view.Then i want to store Textview data. please help.i am trying but i am fail.
 Activity_main.xml//

```
        />

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Edit"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Edit1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Add"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:onClick="add"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sub"
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            android:onClick="sub"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pr"
            android:text="Previoues Data"
           />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

the java file is
MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    EditText Edit,Edit1;

    Button add, sub, pr;
    TextView view;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit);
        Edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit1);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
       sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
       pr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pr);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
       Edit.setText("0");


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int value1 = Integer.parseInt(Edit.getText().toString());
                int value2 = Integer.parseInt(Edit1.getText().toString());
              int result = value1 + value2;
            view.setText(Integer.toString(result));
//          Edit.setText(Integer.toString(result));
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Mydata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("value",result);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int value1 = Integer.parseInt(Edit.getText().toString());
                int value2 = Integer.parseInt(Edit1.getText().toString());
               int result = value1 - value2;
                view.setText(Integer.toString(result));
               Edit.setText(Integer.toString(result));

            }
        });
        pr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Mydata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//                int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);

                String v=sharedPreferences.getInt("value","");
                view.setText(v);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: what´s the error? Could you attach the stack trace?

Comment: when i add buuton click button are not work and data are not store

Comment: but sub button is working,basic problem is  SharedPreferences .(storing data)

Comment: still saying nothing about the error... have u decided wether Preethi answer or mine is your way?? because you have to solve that even when it works... It is working in your device/emulator and may/will crash eventually

Comment: Actually the problem  is, i am trying to storing result which is show in Textview.

Comment: mh... sorry about the misunderstanding... I am not talking about "the problem the application solves" but "the problem you´re facing while saving". Any crash? No results found? ...?

Comment: i am changing the in pr.onClicklisetner String va=sharedPreferences.getString("value","");then add button is working but data are not saved.

Comment: `String v=sharedPreferences.getInt("value","");` does not compile because second parameter should be an `int`. And return type is int.

Comment: you have so much confusion .. First decide you want integer or string depending on that use the method .. at one place you are saving it as integer and another place reading it as string !! again the change you are doing it in one place

Comment: The solutation is v = Integer.toString(sharedPreferences.getInt("value",0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your xml file remove **onClick** from your button

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Add"
        android:id="@+id/add"
      />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sub"
        android:id="@+id/sub"
       />
```

Problem is with your getting value from sharedPreference

```
  String v=sharedPreferences.getInt("value","");
```

why are you passing string as default value and your 
try this String

`v = Integer.toString(sharedPreferences.getInt("value",0));`

Answer (score 0):

in the layout you´ve got `android:onClick="add"` there should be a `public void add(View v)` to handle the event. Do the sum inside that handler.

Please, follow the documentation 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html and see the `:onCLick` handling.